Shift To Sprint
I am attempting to make a program in Lua to sprint while shifting however im getting an "attempt to index nil" error
local UserInputSerive = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Character = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

UserInputSerive.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessed)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 35
    end
end)

UserInputSerive.InputEnded:Connect(function(input, gameProcessed)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
    end
end)


Please provide your full error message, not just its name - see Why should I post complete errors? Why isn't the message itself enough?

That's particularly important since I can't reproduce this problem. You may have put this in a server script instead of a local script or something similar; there's no way of knowing without a full error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
